# Split dataframe column into quantile with no duplication of quantile for any value in R

Tags: r, quantile

I have a data frame defined as below:

```
  structure(list(value = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I want to split column 'value' into 'n' quantile (let say n=3) such that any value should not fall into 2 quantile.
For ex: value '2' should get unique quantile

I tried using 'ntile' function as below

```
df1 <- mutate(df,R_rank=ntile(df$value,3))
```

Result is:

```
structure(list(value = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5), R_rank = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Here value '2' is falling into 2 different quantile (1 and 2) but I want any value should fall into unique quantile.

How can I do this in R ?

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check now

Comment: That is not your expected output, that is output that you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the solution is to set the `quantile` argument `type` to a value other than the default value `type = 7`.

```
n <- 3

q5 <- quantile(V, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = n + 1), type = 5)
q6 <- quantile(V, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = n + 1), type = 6)
q8 <- quantile(V, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = n + 1), type = 8)
q9 <- quantile(V, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = n + 1), type = 9)
```

And to split the input vector:

```
split(V, findInterval(V, q5))
split(V, findInterval(V, q6))
split(V, findInterval(V, q8))
split(V, findInterval(V, q9))
```

The `split` instructions above all give the same results. See below.

The values 5, 6, 8 and 9 were found with the following code:

```
sapply(1:9, function(i)
  quantile(V, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = n + 1), type = i)
)
#          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]     [,5]     [,6] [,7]     [,8]     [,9]
#0%           1    1    1    1 1.000000 1.000000    1 1.000000 1.000000
#33.33333%    2    2    2    2 2.000000 2.000000    2 2.000000 2.000000
#66.66667%    2    2    2    2 2.166667 2.333333    2 2.222222 2.208333
#100%         5    5    5    5 5.000000 5.000000    5 5.000000 5.000000
```

As columns 5, 6, 8 and 9 have the `2/3` quantiles different from `2`, those types can be chosen to address the question.

The `2/3` quantiles are all between 2 and 3, that's the reason why the `split` instructions all output the same list.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can use `cut`

```
cut(df$value, 3, labels = FALSE)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3
```

where

```
df$value #is
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5
```

So 1-2 fall into group 1, 3 falls into group 2 and 4-5 in group3.